# Merge modules missing vc90_mfc_x86.msm and all the rest vc90* files

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, windows-8, setup-project

I'm running Windows 8 and have installed Visual Studio 2010 and 2012.
I'm trying to build a setup project that is using `vc90_mfc_x86.msm`.  The build fails since all the `vc90*` files are missing in the merge modules. There are only `vc100*` and `vc110*` files.

Where do I find the missing `vc90*.msm` files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VC90 is IDE VS2008! If you have only installed the VS2010, then the VC90 MSM files will not be present.
You need to install VS2008 in order to have the VC90 MSM files.